# PHP - Separate a string with comma

Tags: php

I am getting value from a API to get the amound spend.
Currently I got this:

> Total invested: € 17101
>
> Total invested(formatted): € Eu 17101,00

What I want:
I want to make the total invested string (fx 17101) to a currency number (171,01).

I have tried to do it with:

```
number_format($jsonData->amount_spent, 2, ',')
```

Sadly nothing was given the result I wanted

Comment: You have a parse error in your code (missing the `'` at the end)

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, not in the code.Thanks for noticing

Comment: if the input is a string '17101' in Euro-Cents devide by 100 and do the format: `echo number_format($input/100, 2, ',', '');`

Comment: Thats it. Mind posting it as answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is a string '17101' in Euro-Cents devide by 100 and then do the format:

```
$input = "17101";
echo number_format($input/100, 2, ',', '');

// output: 171,01
```

Also note that

> This function accepts either one, two, or four parameters (not three):

[from the Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)